# Exception while deploying the app Invalid ejb jar : it contains zero ejb

Tags: jar, glassfish, ejb

When I change branch in git suddenly this error pop out, tried to add and remove glassfish, clean it, have @stateless and ejb-jar.xml too in my ear.

*I'm not using maven*

Note :

```
    1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or 
       message-driven bean. 
    2. EJB3  entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
    3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton), please check server.log to see whether the annotations were processed properly.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Server Log :

> at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:147)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:112)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:625)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:757)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:121)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:625)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:703)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:248)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:193)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

My application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="7">
  <display-name>AdrenaApp</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>AdrenaEJBMst.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>AdrenaWeb.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>AdrenaWeb</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Comment: If it is a simple EJB.jar I would test to deploy it as is - not in EAR - maybe try a different server vendor the errors are sometimes not really clear. Maybe there is a missmatch for the ejb-jar.xml and annotations?

Comment: Please show the content of your ejb-jar.xml file to your question